# Интервал как список дат

Tags: postgresql

Здравствуйте, разработчики!

Пытаюсь получить список дат в некотором интервале. Например, если заданы начало и окончание месяца/недели. Сделать это надо, чтобы снова же вывести не только значения, которые есть в БД, но и нули - значения, которых в конкретную дату не было.

Игрался с вот этим

```
SELECT current_date + s.a as dates  FROM generate_series(0,30) as s(a);
```

Но не срастается у меня сделать тот же запрос, только учитывая начало месяца, не могу понять, что к какому типу приводить

```
current_date - (current_date - date_trunc('month', current_date))
```

Спасибо за помощь и любые мысли.

**Решение**

```
SELECT (current_date - (current_date - date_trunc('month', current_date))) + (s.a || ' day')::interval
FROM generate_series(0, 30) as s(a);
```

Comment: Можно и иначе

     select d1.dd, d.dat from (select current_date-cast(extract(day from current_date) as integer)+generate_series as dd from generate_series(1, 30)) d1 left join d on d1.dd = d.dat

Comment: @alexlz, в конечном счете почти так оно все и работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Генерируете ваш интервал в таблицу, потом связываете по LEFT JOIN с таблицей из которой необходимо что то там сделать.

Comment: Пример можно? У меня нет прав на CREATE/UPDATE/DELTE, только SELECT.